# Spring Boot REST JPA JSON format

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, spring-rest

I am writing a REST service with Spring Boot and JPA. I have one to many mapping in a table with composite keys. Suppose if parent table "Order" has 2 composite keys (order id, sales date), and "Order detail" has multiple items of that order with 3 composite keys (order id, sales date and item id), how should my request object be. I want to know whether it possible not to set joined column properties explicitly and persist the objects; like I want to send the following POST payload and map it to Order object. This mapping will not set values for salesDate and orderId which are OrderDetail's composite keys. Because of this persist fails due to duplicates.

```
{
    "salesDate": "2016-02-12",
    "orderId": 12,
    "Description":"Sample order",
    "orderDetail":[{
      "itemId": 1231,
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "itemId": 23342,
      "quantity": 1
    }]
}
```

Order.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDR")
@IdClass(OrderId.class)
public class Order implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2496620945369260577L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SLS_DT")
    private Date salesDate;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ORDR_ID")
    private int orderId;

    @Column(name = "ORDR_DESC")
    private short orderDescription;

    @Column(name = "CUST_ID")
    private int customerId;

    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "order")
    private List<OrderDetail> orderItems;

    public Date getSalesDate() {
        return salesDate;
    }

    public void setSalesDate(Date salesDate) {
        this.salesDate = salesDate;
    }

    public int getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(int orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public short getOrderDescription() {
        return orderDescription;
    }

    public void setOrderDescription(short orderDescription) {
        this.orderDescription = orderDescription;
    }

    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
}
```

OrderId.java:

```
public class OrderId {

    private Date salesDate;
    private int orderId;

    public Date getSalesDate() {
        return salesDate;
    }
    public void setSalesDate(Date salesDate) {
        this.salesDate = salesDate;
    }
    public int getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }
    public void setOrderId(int orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }   
}
```

OrderDetail.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "ORDR_DTL")
@IdClass(OrderDetail.class)
public class OrderDetail implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3603127094767197954L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SLS_DT")
    private Date salesDate;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ORDR_ID")
    private int orderId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ITEM_ID")
    private int itemId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "SLS_DT", referencedColumnName = "SLS_DT", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "ORDR_ID", referencedColumnName = "ORDR_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
    private Order order;

    private BigDecimal quantity;

    public Date getSalesDate() {
        return salesDate;
    }

    public void setSalesDate(Date salesDate) {
        this.salesDate = salesDate;
    }

    public int getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(int orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(int itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public BigDecimal getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(BigDecimal quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

OrderDetailId.java:

```
public class OrderDetailId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2312835624801595602L;
    private Date salesDate;
    private int orderId;
    public Date getSalesDate() {
        return salesDate;
    }
    public void setSalesDate(Date salesDate) {
        this.salesDate = salesDate;
    }
    public int getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }
    public void setOrderId(int orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }
    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }
    public void setItemId(int itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }
    private int itemId;
}
```

If I pass the following JSON it works as expected. But I don't want to repeat the keys in the order details and don't want to expose the data base structure to the client.

```
{
    "salesDate": "2016-02-12",
    "orderId": 12,
    "Description": "Sample order",
    "orderDetail": [{
        "salesDate": "2016-02-12",
        "orderId": 12,
        "itemId": 1231,
        "quantity": 2
    }, {
        "salesDate": "2016-02-12",
        "orderId": 12,
        "itemId": 23342,
        "quantity": 1
    }]
}
```

I can pass the first json and transform it into JPA entities. But I believe there should be a cleaner approach to it. The JPA documentation does not help much with this context. Please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `@JsonIgnore` annotation on the `orderId` member of `OrderDetailId`. That should suppress the member from JSON output.

```
@JsonIgnore
private int orderId;
```

Also there's the class annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"memberName"})`. You don't have to mark every member "inside" the class sourcecode.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"orderId"})
public class OrderDetail implements Serializable {
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know we can use @JsonIgnore for response. But I am talking about request payload here. I want to post json that is persisted without reformatting the request to actual database entity structure.